Could not access versionCode from a Flutter extension
In Flutter version 3.22.3, I have this error when building the app for an Android device:
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not get unknown property 'versionCode' for extension 'flutter' of type FlutterExtension.

I think the error originates from the android\app\build.gradle file.
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.flutter_application_1"
    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.flutter_application_1"
        minSdk = flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode = flutter.versionCode         // ERROR HERE
        versionName = flutter.versionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source = "../.."
}

I found similar problems on StackOverflow where the author had problem with ndkVersion and the answer recommended changing flutter.ndkVersion to an explicit one.
Replacing the versionCode and versionName with explicit values makes the app launch successfully.
...
versionCode = 1
versionName = "1.0"
...

However, I don't want to do that for the versionCode, because the versionCode should be the same for all targets. If I write it explicitly in the build.gradle, for example 1.0.0+1 and the version changes to 1.2.3+4, I will probably forget to change it manually.
I have to use Flutter version 3.22.3, I cannot upgrade to version 3.24.0 because of this issue.
How can I fix this so that the versionCode is accessible from the Flutter extension inside the build.gradle file without any errors?

You need to upgrade to Flutter 3.24.0
https://docs.flutter.dev/release/release-notes/release-notes-3.24.0

Unfortunately, because of this issue I have to stay on version 3.22.3.
